# Are there folder size limitations on virtual directory in IIS 7.5?

Tags: iis, asp-classic, filesystemobject, iis-manager

I have a couple virtual directories in IIS 7.5 that point to network resources. Specifically, these folders hold PDF files. I've granted a user permission to these folders, and their contents are accessible via web requests as I would expect. For example, `http://mysite/dir1/test.pdf` works perfectly for both virtual directories. However, when I try to expand one of the virtual directories (the other works fine) to see sub folders, IIS Manager becomes unresponsive almost immediately.

I'm attempting to list the file names of all PDFs in virtual directory on a classic ASP page.

```
Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
filepath = Server.MapPath("/resources/myfolder")
Set folder = objFSO.GetFolder(filepath)
For Each file in folder.Files
    If file.Type = "PDF File" Then
        Response.Write("<p>" & file.Name & "</p>")
    End If
End If

Set folder = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

On a separate page, I using identical code to list the contents of another virtual directory. However, this other directory (as with IIS Manager) causes problems by not responding. It causes the entire site to become unresponsive and I have to recycle to app pool to get it to come back.

The effective permissions for the user account used to access these resources are identical. All files are accessible, and I've confirmed they exist via hardcoding `fso.FileExists(filepath & filename)`. I've also confirmed that the folder object exists and it's properties are being set. Even the `folder.Files.Count` is set properly in both cases. The issue is that the call to iterate through `folder.Files` causes the unresponsive behavior. Are there file size and/or folder size limitations? The only difference I see between the two directories is the number of files and consequently the size of the folder. The one that doesn't work is just over 1GB.

Comment: Just how many files are we talking about? Does the this code run as IUSR or as authetnicate user?  Does the either IUSR or the authenticated user have permissions to the UNC share and folder?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about the size limitations exists. I would assume the limitations is the size of my machine storage. As for showing a list of all the files inside the folder, when the list gets long, you may run into some speed issue. To get the filepath and so on will result in file I/O operation that take more resources. I would design my application that everytime a user post a new PDF, i store the file details (name, location) in a database and then throw the image inside the folder.
THis way, when a user wants to retrieve the file, i do a file grab (which is file I/O and take more resource) and if i want to just show a list of file, i read it off a database table that would be more than 4 columns wide and the database can handle millions of row read easily.